# Selecting specific fields from database table

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-6

I have this code, which selects content types from database, and then build its view depends on content types.

```
$q = db_query('SELECT n.nid, n.title, r.body, f.filename
FROM {node} n
INNER JOIN {node_revisions} r ON n.vid = r.vid
INNER JOIN {content_type_brands} p ON p.nid = n.nid
INNER JOIN {files} f ON f.fid = p.field_deyat_pic_fid
WHERE n.type =  "brands"');
```

But it displays every content type, when i need to make this code to show only specific content types. Hod do i do to show only selected content types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `n` to `p` in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT  n.nid, n.title, r.body, f.filename
FROM    {node} n
            INNER JOIN {node_revisions} r 
                ON n.vid = r.vid
            INNER JOIN {content_type_brands} p 
                ON p.nid = n.nid
            INNER JOIN {files} f 
                ON f.fid = p.field_deyat_pic_fid
// WHERE    p.type =  'brands'
WHERE p.type IN ('brand1','brand1','brand1')
```

Comment: How will it change output results?

Comment: your query based its `type` on `node`. this query is based on `{content_type_brands}`

Comment: changing n to p gave me blank page, with no results. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: how about changing it to multiple values? BTW, can you upload sample records and your desired result? It helps you explain your question. :)

Comment: Well here is site: ultrastep.ru/assortiment, its in russian, but what do i have to do, its to make some of brands on that page to hide. As i found where is this block builds, i decided, to filter brands before they show on page. If i understood correctly structure of DB, there is table called node_revision, and in this table there is field called 'title' which represent titles of content type. I have to print only selected content types, not all that match filter

Comment: I changed where p.type="brands" to   WHERE r.title =  "Утеплитель", but how can i use multiply values?

Comment: do it like this:  `r.title IN ("Val1","Val2","Val3",...,"ValN")`